# Download sklearn datasets behind a proxy

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I installed sklearn in my enviorment and running it now on jupyter notebook on windows.

How can I avoid the error:

> URLError: urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

I am running the following code:

```
import sklearn
import sklearn.ensemble
import sklearn.metrics
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
categories = ['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian']
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories)
```

which gives the error with line 5:

> ----> 3 newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories)

I am behind a proxy on my working computer, is there any option to avoid this error and to be able to use the sample datasets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/5f3c3f037/sklearn/datasets/_twenty_newsgroups.py#L55), scikit-learn will download the file from:

```
https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5975967
```

I am assuming that you cannot reach this location from behind the proxy.

Can you access the dataset by some other means? If yes, then you can download it manually and then run the following script on it:

and keep it at the location:

```
~/scikit_learn_data/
```

Here `~` refers to the user home folder. You can use the following code to know the default location of that folder according to your system.

```
from sklearn.datasets import get_data_home
print(get_data_home())
```

**Update**: Once done, use the following script to make it in a form in which scikit-learn keeps its caches

```
import codecs, pickle, tarfile, shutil
from sklearn.datasets import load_files

data_folder = '~/scikit_learn_data/'
target_folder = data_folder+'20news_home/'

tarfile.open(data_folder+'20newsbydate.tar.gz', "r:gz").extractall(path=target_folder)
cache = dict(train=load_files(target_folder+'20news-bydate-train', encoding='latin1'),
             test=load_files(target_folder+'20news-bydate-test', encoding='latin1'))

compressed_content = codecs.encode(pickle.dumps(cache), 'zlib_codec')

with open(data_folder+'20news-bydate_py3.pkz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(compressed_content)

shutil.rmtree(target_folder)
```

Scikit-learn will always check if the dataset exists locally before attempting to download from internet. For that it will check the above location.

After that you can run the import normally.

Comment: I downloaded it, what is the name to save it in my home folder? Right now I saved it as: `20news-bydate.tar.gz` and it sitll gives the error, home directory is correct

Comment: @PV8 I have updated the answer, please check now. I overlooked the fact the scikit will re-convert the downloaded file into pkz file for faster access times.

Comment: It works, thx, but I think i do not need the command `shutil.rmtree(target folder) this leads to an error

Comment: @PV8 Thats just for removing the extracted directory. You can exclude that if you want

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment proxy for your Python script as follows:

```py
import os

# Replace the placeholders with your actual proxy information
proxy = 'http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'

os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy

# Now, you can run your script as usual
# Your code goes here...
```

Make sure to replace `<user>`, `<pass>`, `<proxy>`, and `<port>` with your actual proxy details. This code sets the environment variables for both HTTP and HTTPS proxies, ensuring that your Python script uses the specified proxy for network requests.